# RocksDB get column family key num

Tags: c++, rocksdb

I used rocksdb C++ API and created some column_families. Now , I want to create an auto-incremental column, so I want to get the total number of keys in the column and then +1.  Is there any way to get the size of column directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that exists out of the box, because there are multiple solutions which have different trade-offs, and rocksdb is more of a library to build databases rather than a fully fledged database in the traditional SQL sense, so they let you make the choice. Providing this out of the box would also require to commit to a solution to maintain this concurrently, and many people don't require this.

Two simple options:

1. transactionally maintain a special record of the size with each column family
2. keep the size in memory and scan the tables at startup to compute it (or alternatively remember the last key), then guard it with a lock and update on modifictions.

I will not go into the more complex options, because I think using e.g. a CRDT makes it non-trivial to ensure that you don't create duplicate keys. For essentially anything that does not imply a total order of operations maintaining the auto-increment will be pretty tricky.

Comment: Hey, midor, Thank you. I will take your advise to make an out box to record the size of each column. and maybe will add an auto scanner to update the statistic info.

Comment: Those are two different approaches to maintain a size. If you don't transactionally maintain the record in the database you are very likely to have a consistency bug later on, if you go with 1.). Scanning over the data is a completely different approach, which increases startup time, but let's you compute the size of columns in memory, which you then still need to maintain transactionally, but you can do that with a lock, and you save yourself the update on the record, which would otherwise certainly be extremely contended, which would limit the overall throughput of your database.